# HttpServletResponse variable is not compiled

Tags: java, servlets, maven-3

I am having problem when compiling the following code

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String method = request.getParameter("method");
    System.out.println(response.toString());
    System.out.println(response);
    response.setHeader("header", "value");
    System.out.println(response.getHeader("header")); // This is line 103 and gives error

    // more logic here
}
```

Basically I am trying to set a header in the response object and I just wanted to test it out whether it was being successfully set or not, that why I am printing it out.

But When I try to compile the above code with maven, it gives the error message below

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.114 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-01-07T09:33:59+05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/312M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project inQuireCatalogWS: Compilation failure
[ERROR] service/catalog/SpexWidgetServlet.java:[103,35] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

what puzzles me is that maven was able to compile the previous lines just fine and only complained about the variable in line where I call the `getHeader()` method. Am I missing something here ?

**EDIT**

My environment is below

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T16:57:37+05:00)
Maven home: /opt/apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.8.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
```

And in `pom.xml`, the entry for `servlet-api` looks like below

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `HttpServletResponse`  just didn't *have* a Method `getHeader()` [until Servlet API 3.0](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#getHeader(java.lang.String))

You could check for [`containsHeader ()`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#containsHeader(java.lang.String)) though. Thats been there a long time. Or simply update to Servlet 3.0 - if your container supports that:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Ahaa ! Got it. The project is bound with `Apache runtime` library and that's bringing in another `servlet-api` jar thats conflicting with the maven jar. Solved. Thanks man